# Communicate between base window and popup window Angular 12

Tags: javascript, angular, popupwindow, angular12

I need to trigger some event from the base window to a popup window when a user tries to open the same popup window again, which is a gear icon dropdown. What are the different ways I can approach this use case? I tried using a service but since the base window and popup window are different angular applications, it's creating a different instance of the service.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class ServiceMessage{
  subscribers: any = [];
  private subject = new Subject<any>();
  sub = this.subject.asObservable();
  a: any = [];
  constructor() {}

  nextSub(data: any) {
    this.subject.next(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: please put your service code too.

Comment: @MahdiJoon Done. But as I said. Using services is useless because they are different angular applications so the reference of the service is also different.

Comment: it is usually better to use built in modals within same page, as angular is designed to be a single page app.

but if you have to, you can check out this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions:

1. If your two applications are deployed in the same domain, use browser storage(local storage or others) to store the information.
   Set a flag in local storage

```
window.localStorage.setItem("isPopOpen", "true");
```

Get the flag from local storage

```
window.localStorage.getItem("isPopOpen");
```

2. If your applications are hosted on different domains, use `Window.postMessage()` to communicate. The `window.postMessage()` method safely enables cross-origin communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

More on `window.postMessage()` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: Thanks. I think window.postMessage() is what I was looking for. I will go through it.